# While publishing to github packages using gradle, only the dependencies are added?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, github-package-registry

f i am publishing my build.gradle to github packages only the dependencies are published or the plugins and tasks are also published. If the tasks and plugins are also published how can i do that ?

Comment: I thinks it depens on your intellij-idea configuration and .gitignore

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.